# How to give command to a different proot distro shell in termux?

Tags: termux

I have a file called debian. I have made a flag of -d. Which turns on the termux-x11 server and the pulse audio server. To make a display I then have to type a different command I created called display which turns on xfce4. Is there any way to pass the command to the pd shell directly?

This is the debian file inside /data/data/com.termux/usr/bin:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "-d" ]; then
        # Start PulseAudio with specific configuration
        pulseaudio --start --load="module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1 auth-anonymous=1" --exit-idle-time=-1

        # Start X11 server in the background
        termux-x11 :1 &

        # Login to Debian using pd with shared tmp
        pd login --shared-tmp debian --user mrdual
else
        pd login --shared-tmp debian --user mrdual
fi
```

This is the display file inside /bin of the debian distro:

```
#creating variables
export DISPLAY=:1 PULSE_SERVER=127.0.0.1

#turning on the xfce server
xfce4-session
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer you have to add a --  flag. So in my case it would be: pd login --shared-tmp debian --user mrdual -- display